# NSPanel borderless but always on top

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-big-sur, nspanel

I am trying to make a `NSPanel` that looks like this

[image: borderless]

This is initialized like that

```
        let panel1 = NSPanel(contentRect: frame1,
                             styleMask: [.borderless],
                             backing: .buffered,
                             defer: true)
```

The thing is, when I click anywhere on the screen outside of that panel, it disappears. Only when i click on the application icon again, it comes to foreground.

With the following implementation I am getting the panel to stick on top, but there its having a border

```
        let panel1 = NSPanel(contentRect: frame1,
                             styleMask: [.borderless, .nonactivatingPanel],
                             backing: .buffered,
                             defer: true)
```

The border (few black pixels) looks like this but is always on top.

[image: border]

#### The question

How can I have it borderless (like the first image) but always on top (like the 2nd image).

#### Notes

- Both variants have `level = .mainMenu`
- Both variants have `collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]`

Comment: Try creating an `NSWindow` rather than an `NSPanel` and maybe also try a different level? HTH

Comment: mh, when chaning it to `NSWindow`the border is gone, but then i have the problem that this window is not on "all spaces in front" (even in "fullscreen spaces")

Comment: If you set the level and collection behavior as before your `NSWindow` should be in front on all spaces. If this is not happening you need to update your question (or ask a new one) showing your full code for creating and configuring the window, then someone will undoubtedly help you figure it out. HTH

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but for whoever is struggling, simply add `hasShadow = false` that will do the trick.